# what is the right way to calculate $\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, conformal-field-theory

It was shown in the answer of the problem [what is the right way to calclulate $\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}?}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475643/what-is-the-right-way-to-calculate-partial-z-frac1-barz?noredirect=1&lq=1) that
\begin{align}
\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}=\pi\delta^{(2)}(\vec{x}),
\end{align}
but when I tried to calclulate $\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}$ further, I found that the answer is depend on the method I used.

**Method $1:$**
\begin{align}
\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}&=\partial_{z}(\frac{1}{\bar{z}}\cdot\frac{1}{\bar{z}})\\
&=2\cdot\frac{1}{\bar{z}}\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\bar{z}}\delta^{(2)}(\vec{x}).
\end{align}
**Method $2:$**
\begin{align}
\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}&=-\partial_{z}\partial_{\bar{z}}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}\\
&=-\partial_{\bar{z}}\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}\\
&=-\pi\partial_{\bar{z}}\delta^{(2)}(\vec{x}).
\end{align}
I tried to prove that the two answers were equivalent because both methods seem natural, and my starting point is $x\delta'(x)=-\delta(x)$, where prime means derivative with respect to x, but it failed.

**comment :** It seems physicist prefer the second answer (I'm a physics student and my tutor provides me with method 2, but he can't explain why method 1 is wrong.)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you have some typos in Method 2 which make it a little difficult to help.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Sorry I can't find the typos you said, could you please be more specific?

Comment: You have a $\partial_{\bar{z}}$ but a second derivative of the Dirac delta.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Sorry I still can't get your point, may be I should list the definition $\partial_{\bar{z}}:=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{x}+i\partial_{y} )$ and $\delta^{(2)}(\vec{x}):=\delta(x)\delta(y)$.

Comment: Oh whoops. I totally missed that the power changed on $\bar{z}$. My apologies!

Comment: @Hezaraki what do you mean by $\partial_z \frac{1}{\overline{z}^2}$ exactly? contrary to $\frac{1}{z}$ or $\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$, the function $\frac{1}{\overline{z}^2}$ is not locally integrable, so it is not a distribution

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki  well thanks, actually I don't know $\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}$ is not a distribution...The motivation I investigate  $\partial_{z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}$ is that I'm not sure whether $\partial_{z}$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}}$  satisfie Leibniz's law or not, when we deal with the formule like it, such as $\partial_{z}\frac{(z+w)(\bar{z}+\bar{w})}{\bar{z}(\bar{z}-\bar{w})}$ , such formula usually occurs in the calculation of conformal field theory, like [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.12603)