# Dirac delta distribution in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In the complex plane, one can write
$$\delta(x) \delta(y) = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \partial_z \dfrac{1}{\bar{z}}.$$

[How to prove this relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475643/what-is-the-right-way-to-calculate-partial-z-frac1-barz) has been answered before and identifies

$$ 2\pi \delta(x) \delta(y) = \partial_x \left(\dfrac{x}{x^2 + y^2}  \right) + \partial_y \left(\dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2}  \right).  $$

However, I have not been able to show that this relation indeed holds. How can I prove that it is indeed true?

Answer (score 4):

Let me write $z = (x,y)$ and $|z|^2 = x^2+y^2$. Then, your second relation can be written
$$
\nabla\cdot(z/|z|^2) = 2\pi\,\delta(z)
$$
where $\delta(z) = \delta(x)\,\delta(y)$ is the Dirac delta in $\Bbb R^2$. This follows from the well-known fact that $-\ln |z|$ is a fundamental solution of the Poisson equation, since then
$$
\nabla\cdot(z/|z|^2) = \nabla\cdot(\nabla(\ln|z|)) = \Delta \ln |z| = 2\pi\,\delta(z).
$$

---

There are a lot of derivations of the Poisson fundamental solution. One can remark that taking the derivative in the classical sense $\Delta \ln |z| = 0$ for $z\neq 0$, use a scaling argument to deduce that $\Delta \ln |z| = C\,\delta(z)$. Another that I prefer is to use the Fourier transform: since (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3/3724502#3724502)) $\mathcal{F}(\ln(z)) = C\,\delta(z) - \mathrm{pf}\frac{1}{2\pi\,|z|^2}$, one deduces that
$$
\mathcal{F}(\Delta\ln(z)) = -C\,4\pi^2 |z|^2\,\delta(z) + 2\pi = 2\pi
$$
because $|z|^2\,\delta(z) = 0$, and so $\Delta\ln(z) = 2\pi\,\delta(z)$.

Answer (score 3):

The strategy is to show that the delta function at the origin in the plane can be approximated by a family of smooth density functions that depend on a parameter $\epsilon \to 0$ that ultimately concentrate their mass at the origin.

First make use of the approximation  $\frac{ 1}{\overline z} = \frac{ z}{ z\overline z} \sim f(z,\overline z)=\frac{ z}{ z\overline z+\epsilon}$ and then  we use the Wirtinger calculus  and quotient rule to compute

$  \partial_z f(z,\overline z)=\partial_z \frac{ z}{z\overline z+ \epsilon} =\frac{ (\epsilon + z\overline z)-z\overline z }{(|z|^2+ \epsilon)^2} =\frac{\epsilon}{(|z|^2+ \epsilon)^2} :=\mu(z,\overline z)$.

Next check that this mass density expression always has the same total mass in the plane; that is, show that  $I=\int \int \mu \ dx \ dy$ is always the same constant regardless of the choice of $\epsilon$. (This is easy to  verify by making the scaled change of variables $x=\sqrt{\epsilon} x', y= \sqrt{\epsilon} y'$ for which $ dx dy = \epsilon dx' dy'$.)

Next you can evaluate this  normalization constant by setting $\epsilon =1$ and then using polar coordinates:

$I= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac {r \ dr \ d\theta}{ (r^2+ 1)^2} = \pi$

Lastly, (handwaving somewhat) you can confirm by graphing the density functions that the mass density distributions concentrate their mass in zones whose radii ultimately tend to zero.

Footnote. The function $f$ and the measure $\mu$ are connected to the Laplacian of perturbations of the log function as follows:  $ \mu=\frac{\partial^2 \ln(\epsilon+ z \overline z)}{\partial z \partial\overline z}$ and $f= \frac{ \partial}{\partial \overline z} \ln(\epsilon+ z \overline z)$.

The usual real-variable Laplacian can be written in Wirtinger notation as $ u_{xx}+u_{yy}= 4 u_{z\overline z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy starts by applying Stokes' theorem to Cauchy's integral formula :
$$
f(\zeta) = \oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i} \frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta} = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i} \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}\frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}
$$
With Cartesian coordinates, i.e. $z = x + iy$, one has $\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge\mathrm{d}z = 2i \,\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y$, hence the following representation of the 2D Dirac delta on the (Cartesian) complex plane :
$$
\delta^{(2)}(x,y) = \delta(x)\delta(y) = \partial_{\bar{z}}\frac{1}{\pi z}
$$
and, by taking the complex conjugate of this relation,
$$
\delta(x)\delta(y) = \partial_z\frac{1}{\pi\bar{z}}.
$$
As for your second identity, it can be proven by interpreting $\partial_z$ as a [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable), as follows :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
2\pi\delta(x)\delta(y) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   2\partial_z\frac{1}{\bar{z}} \quad\mathrm{with}\quad \frac{1}{\bar{z}} = \frac{z}{|z|^2} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   (\partial_x - i\partial_y) \frac{x+iy}{x^2+y^2} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \partial_x\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} + \partial_y\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} + i\partial_x\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} - i\partial_y\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \partial_x\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} + \partial_y\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}
\end{array}
$$
because the last two terms compensate each other.

Comment: Thank you. For your second proof, I don't understand the following: you say the last two terms compensate each other, which I agree with. However, applying the derivatives on the first two terms also gives me zero... why don't these vanish as well?